# Is equal sign = partial ordering?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm studying analysis and there is a problem

Let X be a set, and let P be the set of all partial orderings of X.
We say that one partial ordering ≤ ∈P is coarser than another partial ordering
≤’∈P if for any x,y∈X, we have the implication (x≤y)⇒(x≤’y).
There is exactly one minimal element of P; what is it?

I think the answer is =. but Is equal sign = odering?

it doesn't look like an ordering sign. usually ordering sign looks asymmetric.

Comment: Well, does it satisfy the definition of a partial ordering?

Comment: A non-strict partial order (typically "partial order") is antisymmetric, not asymmetric, so it doesn't matter that $=$ isn't asymmetric.  Is it antisymmetric? (if it helps, think about what the the Hasse diagram of an antichain looks like)

Comment: The symbol which we use to denote a relation doesn't necessarily need to signify that the relationship is asymmetric (or antisymmetric, for that matter). Take, for example, the division relation $a \mid b \iff \exists c(ac = b)$. We have $6\mid 12$ while $12\not\mid 6$, but you wouldn't know it from the appearance of the symbol $\mid$ alone. The $=$ relation is a partial order like any other. It is also an equivalence relation, which is stronger than being a partial order. It is also equality, which is stronger than being an equivalence relation too. But it is still a partial order as well.

Comment: @RobBland thanks! I got it.

Comment: @EricWofsey yes this sign = satisfies 1.reflexive 2.anti-symmetric 3.transitive. I just thought that its appearance looks asymmetric.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks!

Comment: @RobBland "is also an equivalence relation, which is stronger than being a partial order." -- Perhaps a minor quibble since your underlying point is made without this statement, but being an equivalence relation is not logically stronger than being a partial order; rather; they're almost disjoint concepts, since at their intersection is only equality.